# Make decimal digits mandatory if dot entered in regex validation

Tags: regex

If regex validation is `^\d{0,10}(\.\d{0,2})?$`, then maximum two digits are required after decimal which is optional.

But it allows "100." also. since the user has not entered any digit after decimal, how to validate and make decimal digits required if dot is entered

Comment: Hint: What do you think the `0` in `{0,2}` means?

Comment: Are you aware that the regex also matches the empty string (which might or might not be desirable)?

Comment: got it I have to make it 1,2

Comment: It can have empty value too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to require 2 digits after the decimal if a period is provided then make your regex look like:

```
/^\d{0,10}(\.\d{2,})?$/
```

`\d{2,}` means that a mininum of two numbers is required - followed by any number of digits (which is why the expression is open-ended, e.g. `2,` - if you require two and only two digits than provide both a lower- and upper-bound: `{2,2}`

Comment: A maximum, not minimum, of 2 digits is required.

Comment: So, "two and only two digits" is `\d{2,2}`

Comment: Nowhere did he say there must be a minimum of two digits.

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
^\d{0,10}(\.\d\d?)?$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/nA5mD3/3)